# ¿Como obtener una variable static desde otra Clase?

Tags: php

Mi problema puede parecer sencillo, pero no he encontrado un motivo de porque me arroja error de sintaxis el editor de código de netbeans.

Mi codigo:

```
class bot extends Valores{
    private $estado;

    function __construct(){

        $this->estado = bot::Valores::$mi_estado;
        print '$estado=' . $this->estado;
    }
}
```

Esta pequeña fracción de código debería poder obtener la variable `statica` `$mi_estado` y guardarlo sobre la variable `$estado` de la clase actual.

Mi otra clase:

```
class Valores
{
    public static $mi_estado = 0;

    public function setEstado($estado) {
        self::$mi_estado=estado;
    }

    public function getEstado() {
        return self::$mi_static;
    }
}
```

Gracias y espero su pronto apoyo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu código debería quedar así:

```
<?php

class Valores
{
    public static $mi_estado = 0;

    public function setEstado($estado) {
        self::$mi_estado=estado;
    }

    public function getEstado() {
        return self::$mi_static;
    }
}


class bot extends Valores{
    private $estado;

    function __construct(){

        $this->estado = Valores::$mi_estado;
        print '$estado=' . $this->estado;
    }
}

$obj = new bot();
print_r($obj);
```

Dando como resultado:

> $estado=0bot Object ( [estado:bot:private] => 0 )

**Observaciones**

- Personalmente veo innecesario esto `bot::Valores::$mi_estado;` pues la clase ya extiende de `Valores`.
- Para que la clase `bot` pueda mostrar al acceso a dicha propiedad, en el método constructor debes igualar la propiedad con el nombre de la clase y el acceso a la propiedad en cuestión de este modo: `Valores::$mi_estado;`
- Por último para mostrar el valor realiza una instancia de la clase de este mo:

---

```
$obj = new bot();
print_r($obj);
```

Hacer esto:

```
bot::Valores::$mi_estado;
```

Es incorrecto por que estás indicando que la clase `bot` trata de acceder a `Valores` como si la clase fuera estática cuando claramente no lo es.

Hacer lo anterior deriva en un error que dice:

> FATAL ERROR syntax error, unexpected '::' (T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM) on line number #

Ya que la sintaxis es:

Si tratas de acceder a un valor estático por fuera del ámbito de la clase, entonces deberá ser así:

```
ClassName::method/property;
```

Si en este caso `bot`ya hereda de `Valores`, ya puede acceder a sus método y propiedades; prueba lo siguiente:

```
echo bot::$mi_estado;
```

Dando como resultado:

> 0

**Referencias.**

- [Operador de resolución de ámbito](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.paamayim-nekudotayim.php)